# Running Total of a count per day in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, running-totals

I usually write a couple of very simple queries on a redshift database which used in a marketing visualization tool.  And I repeat - VERY simple - I am a novice at this.

I am now faced with a new data source (SQLite) and I'm stuck.

I have a table with :

- `order_id`
- `order_date`

where there are several orders per day.  And I am trying to get a running total of the daily count of order ids.

For example the table would contain :

```
order_id      order_date  
2541          2017-06-05  
26777         2017-06-05  
123           2017-06-06  
8795          2017-06-07
```

And I'm trying to get to this result :

```
Day          RunningTotal  
2017-06-05 : 2  
2017-06-06 : 3  (the 2 of the previous day + 1 this day)  
2017-06-07 : 4
```

In POSTGRESQL i would use

```
SELECT  
order_date,  
SUM (COUNT(order_id)) OVER (ORDER BY order_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as RunningTotal
FROM table  
ORDER BY  
order_date  
GROUP BY  
order_date
```

How do I do this in SQLite?

I've googled - and see many examples of either SUM or COUNT but seldom combined and never to achieve a running total of a count.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying something similar : this is what worked in the end :

```
select
a.ORDER_DATE,
sum(b.ID_COUNT) RunningTotal
from
(select
ORDER_DATE, Count(DISTINCT(SOFTWARE_ID)) ID_COUNT
from orders
group by ORDER_DATE
order by ORDER_DATE) a,
(select
ORDER_DATE, Count(DISTINCT(SOFTWARE_ID)) ID_COUNT
from orders
group by ORDER_DATE
order by ORDER_DATE) b
where a.ORDER_DATE >= b.ORDER_DATE
group by a.ORDER_DATE
order by a.ORDER_DATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:  create a view that delivers the COUNT() for each day, then use this view (in a query) to calculate the running total (with SUM()):

```
create view order_view
as
select
  order_date
, count(order_id) order_count
from orders 
group by order_date 
order by order_date ;
```

This delivers (using your test data):

```
select * from order_view
-- output
order_date  order_count
2017-06-05  2
2017-06-06  1
2017-06-07  1
```

Then, use something like ...

```
select 
  a.order_date
, sum(b.order_count) RunningTotal
from 
  order_view a
, order_view b
where a.order_date >= b.order_date
group by a.order_date
order by a.order_date;

-- output
order_date   RunningTotal
2017-06-05   2
2017-06-06   3
2017-06-07   4
```

See also: [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=8f7f4b03e90eee491b2df225743b6278).
Note that "SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times." (see https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't quite able to use it exactly as described above because this Query Visualization Tool does not seem to allow View.  But it did get me to start thinking about a different approach!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT id,
       strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', tarih / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') alis_tarihi,
       alis_fiyati,
       kalan_adet,
       adet,
       kdv,
       SUM (adet) OVER (
                        ORDER BY tarih)
FROM satin_alma
WHERE urun_satis_durumu IN (0, 1)
  AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', tarih / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') < '2019-04-29 09:45'
```

```
18  2019-04-28 02:14    25  30  30  8   30
5   2019-04-28 11:17    30  20  25  4   55
12  2019-04-29 09:43    40  20  20  4   75
```

Comment: Welcome on the site! Note, code-only answers are typically not a very high quality. Please explain, what you did and how.

Answer (score -4):

you can simply do like this

```
select order_date, count(order_date) from orders
group by order_date
```

Comment: Your query only calculates the number of rows with a matching date, not the total over time. For example, if you have a count of 2 each day, after 3 days the query would show 6 for the third day, not 2.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE, thank you for taking the time to answer! Please could you edit your answer so that it provides a solution to the problem?